# Continuous servo takes time to stop?

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, pwm, servo

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 to control a modified TowerPro SG90 servo, where I have removed the potentiometer to make a continuous rotation servo.

Using the code below, the motor starts exactly when I tell it to, but when I tell it to stop, it takes ~1 second to stop, by which time it has completed around another half-turn.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(17, 50)
p.start(0)

while True:
    input()
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
    input()
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
```

There is also a (possibly related?) issue where anything between a 1 to 1.8 millisecond pulse will turn the servo one way, and only a 2 millisecond pulse will turn the servo the other.

I have tried the same code on a Pico running CircuitPython, with identical results.

Comment: You are not telling the servo to stop.  You are just not sending servo signals.  Try controlling the servos with [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#S/SERVO).

Comment: What did you do with the potentiometer leads, leave them open? Can you post a link to the schematic of that showing the potentiometer and associated connections etc.

Comment: Did you totally remove the pot? All the ways I remember doing this involve removing the pot from the motor, but still leaving it connected, then setting it so that a 1.5ms pulse leaves the servo not moving. Longer pulses should move it one way; shorter, the other. Then glue the pot so it can't move.